# LinkedIn make authenticated api call to return json data

Tags: json, api, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

The linkedin document clearly shows how to retrieve json format when making an api call.
For example:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id)?format=json
```

However, I need to make an authenticated api call, which means that I include the accesss token in the url. The structure is as follows...

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE
```

I have retrieved the default xml data but dont understand from their documents how i can make an authenticated call and get json format.

Relavent link
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/api-requests-json

Answer (score 4):

For presenting an OAuth 2.0 access token to a protected API it is best (according to the OAuth 2.0 standard) to present the token in a header as follows (using cURL):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id)?format=json"
```